# Why is env.MSBuildEmitSolution set by TeamCity?

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity

When I use an MSBuild step and run the build, I see that the property  env.MSBuildEmitSolution is set to 1.
Why does TeamCity set this env variable to 1?
And how can I disable it ?

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild is quietly generating temporary projects in-memory, from the .sln file.  In order have these files saved to disk, you would set env.MSBuildEmitSolution = 1.  More details [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/823876/error-msb4025-when-using-solution-level-build-ordering-and-manipulating-projectreference-items)